# C#: Can I have no entry point for a Project?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a C#/WPF project mainly for providing dialogs for use in other projects. I originally have an `app.config` but deleted it as the project is meant to be more like a library. I then got the errors

> Metadata file
>   'D:\projects\SimpleColorPicker\SimpleColorPicker\bin\Debug\SimpleColorPicker.exe'
>   could not be found
>
> \SimpleColorPicker.exe' does not
>   contain a static 'Main' method
>   suitable for an entry
>   point D:\projects\SimpleColorPicker\SimpleColorPicker\CSC

How can I fix this? I could leave the app.config in but I thought it will be neater to clean unneeded stuff

Comment: Is your `Project Properties-->Application-->Output Type` set on `Class Library` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a class library (DLL) rather than an application. A DLL assembly is basically an executable without an entry point. Take a look at the output type in the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your project from a Windows/Console Application to a Class Library in the Project Properties on the Application tab.  Then you won't be able to "run" this project in isolation, but if it is a library project then that is what you want.